# does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git

I am trying to set-up a production push to my server:

Remote Server:

In my `public_html` dir I have created a folder called `Template.git`

In my `Template.git/hooks/post-receive` file I have added:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/USER/public_html/Template.git/git checkout -f
```

My `Template.git` config file has the following in it:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true`
```

Local Computer:

I have added a production setting:

```
remote add production USER@DOMAIN:Template.git
```

When I run the following:

```
git push production +master:refs/heads/master
```

I get the following:

```
stdin: is not a tty
fatal: 'Template.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How do I fix the above error?

Comment: How are you hosting the template.git? Is it the git daemon or are you access it via ssh? Or is the repository on local disk?

Comment: try `USER@DOMAIN:public_html/Template.git`